# Delete pictures in PowerPoint using VBA macro

Tags: image, vba, powerpoint

I am using the following VBA Macro to delete all the pictures in a PowerPoint slide:

```
Public Function delete_slide_object(slide_no)
     ' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
     ' Reference active presentation
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
     ' Delete object in slide
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(slide_no)
    For Each PPShape In PPSlide.Shapes
        If PPShape.Type = msoPicture Then
            PPShape.Delete
        End If
    Next PPShape

    Set PPShape = Nothing
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
End Function
```

This code is deleting some but not all the pictures.After running this code 3 times , all the pictures get deleted. Where am i going wrong? Kindly let me know

Comment: Have they had a chance to try the answer yet?

Comment: Hey Hi! Just tried the code. Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When deleting items from a collection, you have to use a different iteration.

Try this:

```
Dim p as Long
For p = PPSlide.Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
    Set PPShape = PPSlide.Shapes(p)
    If PPShape.Type = msoPicture Then PPShape.Delete
Next
```

This is because the collection is re-indexed when items are removed, so if you delete `Shapes(2)` then what was previously `Shapes(3)` becomes `Shapes(2)` after the deletion, and is effectively "skipped" by the loop.  To avoid this, you have to start with the *last* shape, and delete them in reverse order.