# Replace existing image in MS PowerPoint with a new image using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm updating my MS PowerPoint by pasting images on different slides using VBA.

Rest of the code is working fine. What I'm unable to do is delete the existing image on all the slides and paste the new image. Currently it paste the new image on top of old image, but old image remains. I'm using below code:

```
Dim pptApp  As PowerPoint.Application
Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

pptApp.Visible = msoTrue

xlApp.Worksheets(2).Range("M2:S12").Copy
Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

With shp1
    .Left = 370
    .Top = 100
    .Height = 360
    .Width = 340
End With
```

Being a newbie to VBA, I dont know where and how to add delete command in above code. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (thanks, L42) will work for single msoPicture shapes on a slide, but if there's more than one shape, it may miss some:

```
Dim s As Shape

For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes
    If s.Type = 13 Then s.Delete '13 is msoPicture
Next
```

Why?  Suppose you have three shapes on the slide.  We iterate through the shapes collection, find that the first shape is a picture and delete it.  Now there are two shapes in the shapes collection, but VBA's counter doesn't take account of changes in the collection count.  It looks at the second shape in the collection, but that's now what WAS the third shape on the slide, so the code will miss shape #2 altogether.

It's more reliable to use something like this:

```
Dim x as Long

For x = ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
    If ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes(x).Type = msoPicture Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes(x).Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You are correct. It's a good thing I learn new things everyday. Plus 1 :)

Comment: Just paying it forward as a way of thanking a friend who paid it forward to me years ago.  ;-)  And thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit1:** As what Steve pointed out, the first posted solution is unreliable; also as confirmed in this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588567/delete-pictures-in-powerpoint-using-vba-macro) by Doug.

To delete all pictures using loop, take Steve's approach as explained in his post.
Now, if you just want to delete all the pictures, you can try this:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes.Range.Delete
```

But this deletes all shapes, not only pictures but textboxes, lines, shapes etc.
To delete only pictures, below is another approach using loop.

```
Dim s As Shape, pictodel As Variant
For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes
    If s.Type = 13 Then
        If IsArray(pictodel) Then
            ReDim Preserve pictodel(UBound(pictodel) + 1)
            pictodel(UBound(pictodel)) = s.Name
        Else
            pictodel = Array(s.Name)
        End If
    End If
Next
ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes.Range(pictodel).Delete
```

Hope this helps but a simpler solution would be Steve's. :)

Comment: Note: L42's code will work unless there's more than one picture shape per slide.  In that case, you'd want to use For x = ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1

Comment: Actually I had many images on a slide, but all of them were of same type, thus this worked fine for me.

Comment: @L42: not exactly. It'll skip every other image.  See longer answer that I'll post shortly.